# Question about transforming a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Consider the following list:

```
{{"id" -> "8792584", "name" -> "Maybank Championship Malaysia", {"marketCount" -> 22, "competitionRegion" -> "GBR"}}, {"id" -> "376041", "name" -> "Indian I League", {"marketCount" -> 20, "competitionRegion" -> "IND"}}}
```

I want to transform this list to the following format:

```
{{"id" -> "8792584", "name" -> "Maybank Championship Malaysia", "marketCount" -> 22, "competitionRegion" -> "GBR"}, {"id" -> "376041", "name" -> "Indian I League", "marketCount" -> 20, "competitionRegion" -> "IND"}}
```

Knowing the power of Mma, my intuition says there must be a very compact way to do this, but I have difficulty in achieving this in a clean, short way. Please help/

Comment: Have you tried `Flatten[]`?

Comment: LOL - Of course. Sadly, does not do the job.

Comment: `Flatten[list, 1]` doesn't work here, then?

Comment: Answer below works, with Flatten ... I am confused.

Comment: Flatten[list,1] did work ( in the case I posted in the question anyway ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bascially you want every element of a `List` to be another `List` of depth 1. Here is an easy way to do that:

```
In:= rules={{"id" -> "8792584", "name" -> "Maybank Championship Malaysia", {"marketCount" -> 22, "competitionRegion" -> "GBR"}}, {"id" -> "376041", "name" -> "Indian I League", {"marketCount" -> 20, "competitionRegion" -> "IND"}}};
In:= Flatten/@rules
out= {{"id" -> "8792584", "name" -> "Maybank Championship Malaysia", "marketCount" -> 22, "competitionRegion" -> "GBR"}, {"id" -> "376041", "name" -> "Indian I League", "marketCount" -> 20, "competitionRegion" -> "IND"}}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted.

Comment: {{a, {b, b}}, {a, {b, b, b}, {c, c}}} This type of structure should become
{ {a, b, b}, {a,b,b,b,c,c} }. Will edit the question when I get new real data.